# Leaflet layer is not removed when checkboxes are unchecked

Tags: javascript, leaflet, jquery-events

I have the the code below to show data on the map by clicking a button associated with checkboxes in leaflet. It works fine when clicking the first time:

```
$("#btnPoiFilter").click(function(){
 console.log(lyrPoi);
  if (lyrPoi) {
  lyrPoi.remove();
 } 
var lyrPoi = L.geoJSON(jsnPoi,{coordsToLatLng:reproject, pointToLayer:returnPoiMarker, filter:filterPoi}).addTo(mymap);   
});
```

The purpose of this part of code is to remove the data showed (lyrPoi) when some of the boxes are unchecked and the button is clicked again, but it doesn't work:

```
if (lyrPoi) { 
lyrPoi.remove();
}
```

When clicking the second time with some boxes unchecked, all the elements remain. The console.log return undefined so I suspect the problem is that lyrPoi is not identified for some reason.
Here the whole event:

```
mymap.on('pm:create',function(e){
                    var jsn = e.layer.toGeoJSON().geometry;
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'load_data_testing.php',
                        data: {id:'geojsonpol', geojsonpol:JSON.stringify(jsn)},
                        type:'POST',
                        success: function(response){
                            if (response.substring(0,5)=="ERROR"){
                                alert(response);
                            } else {
                                alert(response);
                                jsnPoi = JSON.parse(response);
                                var fromProjection = '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs';
                                var toProjection = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs ";         
                                $("#btnPoiFilter").click(function(){
                                    console.log(lyrPoi)
                                    if (lyrPoi) {
                                        lyrPoi.remove();
                                    } 
                                        var lyrPoi = L.geoJSON(jsnPoi,{coordsToLatLng:reproject, pointToLayer:returnPoiMarker, filter:filterPoi}).addTo(mymap);   
                                });

                                }
                             },
                            error: function(xhr, status, error){
                               alert("ERROR: "+error);
                            }
                        });
                    });
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very bad what are you doing. The Problem is, every time you create a layer you add a new click event to `$("#btnPoiFilter")`.

Change your code to:

```
var fromProjection = '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs';
var toProjection = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs ";         

// Have to be defined here or else where
var lyrPoi;
var jsPoi;
$("#btnPoiFilter").click(function(){
   console.log(lyrPoi)
   if (lyrPoi) {
        lyrPoi.remove();
   }
   if(jsPoi){
        lyrPoi = L.geoJSON(jsnPoi,{coordsToLatLng:reproject, pointToLayer:returnPoiMarker, filter:filterPoi}).addTo(mymap);   
   }
});

mymap.on('pm:create',function(e){
                    var jsn = e.layer.toGeoJSON().geometry;
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'load_data_testing.php',
                        data: {id:'geojsonpol', geojsonpol:JSON.stringify(jsn)},
                        type:'POST',
                        success: function(response){
                            if (response.substring(0,5)=="ERROR"){
                                alert(response);
                            } else {
                                alert(response);
                                jsnPoi = JSON.parse(response);
                            }
                         },
                         error: function(xhr, status, error){
                             alert("ERROR: "+error);
                         }
                        });
                    });
```

But with that you will always have the problem, that when you create two polygons and then the button is clicked, only the points from the second one are showing.

I recommend to do it so, if it is allowed to draw multiple polygons:

```
var fromProjection = '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs';
var toProjection = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs ";         

var lyrPoi = L.geoJSON(null,{coordsToLatLng:reproject, pointToLayer:returnPoiMarker, filter:filterPoi});
$("#btnPoiFilter").click(function(){
   // Toggle layer
   if(map.hasLayer(lyrPoi)){
      lyrPoi.removeFrom(map);
   }else{
      lyrPoi.addTo(map);
   }
});

mymap.on('pm:create',function(e){
                    var jsn = e.layer.toGeoJSON().geometry;
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'load_data_testing.php',
                        data: {id:'geojsonpol', geojsonpol:JSON.stringify(jsn)},
                        type:'POST',
                        success: function(response){
                            if (response.substring(0,5)=="ERROR"){
                                alert(response);
                            } else {
                                alert(response);
                                var jsnPoi = JSON.parse(response);
                                lyrPoi.addData(jsnPoi);
                            }
                         },
                         error: function(xhr, status, error){
                             alert("ERROR: "+error);
                         }
                        });
                    });
```

Comment: Thank you vey much for your answer, really really helpful. 
I've slightly modified the first piece of code to adapt it to my workflow and now works as expected. The second one works fine but it doesn't provide the functionality I want to offer: draw the polygon -> check/uncheck checkboxes-> click the button -> get the POIs within the polygon. After that, if the user changes his mind and check/uncheck the boxes, the application should be able to refresh and shows the new POIs. The second solution doesn't work that way as you are not allow to go back and change previous polygons.
Cheers.